# How to do multi-level pull of array element in mgo?

Tags: go, mgo

I want to do a multi-level array element delete. My Structs are as follows:-

```
type Company struct {
    Id              bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    CompanyName     string
    Process         []ProcessItem
}

type ProcessItem  struct{
    SortOrder       int
    Documents       []DocumentTemplate
}

type DocumentTemplate struct {
    Id              bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    TemplateName    string
}
```

I want to delete an object of type DocumentTemplate. The DocumentTemplate is a struct array in ProcessItem which is a struct array in Company struct. I have Company Id(field of struct Company) and TemplateName(field of struct DocumentTemplate).

I tried the below mgo pull query but it is not working.

```
c := db.C("company")
pullQuery := bson.M{"process": bson.M{"documents.templatename": "xyz"}}
err := c.Update(bson.M{"_id": "123"}, bson.M{"$pull": pullQuery})
```

Please point out the mistakes I made here. Thanks.

**Edit:**
Adding one example document for the clarity of the question

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("573da7dddd73171e42a84045"),
    "companyname" : "AAA",
    "process" : [ 
        {
            "processname" : "Enquiry",
            "sortorder" : 0,
            "documents" : [ 
                {
                    "templatename" : "xyz",
                    "processname" : "Enquiry"
                }, 
                {
                    "templatename" : "ss",
                    "processname" : "Enquiry"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "processname" : "Converted",
            "processtype" : 1,
            "sortorder" : 2,
            "documents" : [ 
                {
                    "templatename" : "dd",
                    "processname" : "Converted"
                }, 
                {
                    "templatename" : "fg",
                    "processname" : "Converted"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to pull out just one DocumentTemplete record, like the one below:

```
{
   "templatename" : "xyz",
   "processname" : "Enquiry"
}
```

N.B: TemplateName will be unique inside a Company.

Comment: Is `TemplateName` unique, or a single `Company` object can hold many `DocumentTemplate` with the same name, and if so, do you want to pull every single one of them?

Comment: @JohnSmith TemplateNames will be unique. I had added validation for that. There will be only one TemplateName "xyz" per Company. Please check out my edit in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the `$` positional operator (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/). In order to be able to use that you'll also have to add to your query the following:

```
"process.documents.templatename": "xyz"
```

Your `Update` statement should look like this:

```
c := db.C("company")
pullQuery := bson.M{"process.$.documents": bson.M{"templatename": "xyz"}}
err := c.Update(bson.M{"_id": "123", "process.documents.templatename": "xyz"}, bson.M{"$pull": pullQuery})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull values in array from the array in mongo record

```
 change2 := bson.M{
                "$pull": bson.M{"sapinfo.systemstatus": bson.M{"$in": tags}},
            }
```